# Como recuperar ID do endereço?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou usando asp.mvc.
Na minha rota tem o ID, o endereço da pagina por exemplo tem http://usuario/1 .

Eu queria pegar esse numero 1 ao final da pagina, tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rota padrão é mais ou menos assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note que é passado um **id** ao final dela, isso indica que quando tiver uma rota, exemplo: http://seusite/Controller/Action/valor quer dizer que é possível pegar esse **valor** criando uma variável **id** na `action`

```
public ActionResult SuaAction(int? id) {}
```

Agora se deseja passar da seguinte forma http://seusite/Controller/valor, seria necessário criar uma rota customizada que ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RotaCustom",
    url: "SuaURL/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode recuperar último segmento, por exemplo:

```
// http://usuario/1
string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string id = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
//resultado: 1
```